# Ajax.Beginform oBegin not giving updated data to controller, its giving updated data second time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I using Ajax.beginform as well as onbegin

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewUser", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "UserRoles.onSuccess", OnFailure = "UserRoles.onFailure", HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "return setValues()" }, new { @class = "" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ServiceCentreId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RoleId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProvinceId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DistrictId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DivisionId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TehsilId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MauzaId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PatwarCircleId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QanoonGoiId)
}

  function setValues() {
            debugger;
            var selectedSCrows = $("#gridSC").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");

            for (var i = 0; i < selectedSCrows.length; i++) {
                var rowScData = $("#gridSC").jqGrid('getRowData', selectedSCrows[i]);
                $("#ServiceCentreId").val($("#ServiceCentreId").val() + ";" + rowScData.ServiceCentreId);
            }
            var rolesGridData = UserRoles.getGridData();
            if (typeof (rolesGridData) != "undefined") {
                for (var j = 0; j < rolesGridData.length; j++) {
                    $("#RoleId").val($("#RoleId").val() + ";" + rolesGridData[j].RoleId);
                    $("#ProvinceId").val($("#ProvinceId").val() + ";" + rolesGridData[j].ProvinceId);
                    $("#DivisionId").val($("#DivisionId").val() + ";" + rolesGridData[j].DivisionId);
                    $("#DistrictId").val($("#DistrictId").val() + ";" + rolesGridData[j].DistrictId);
                    $("#TehsilId").val($("#TehsilId").val() + ";" + rolesGridData[j].TehsilId);
                    $("#QanoonGoiId").val($("#QanoonGoiId").val() + ";" + rolesGridData[j].QanoonGoiId);
                    $("#PatwarCircleId").val($("#PatwarCircleId").val() + ";" + rolesGridData[j].PatwarCircleId);
                    $("#MauzaId").val($("#MauzaId").val() + ";" + rolesGridData[j].MauzaId);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

But I am not getting the updated values in controller. I have debugged the java script function setvalues is calling but I am unable to receive it at server side.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewUser(NewUser newUser)
        {




            return View(newuser);
        }
```

Comment: Please post the action which receives this post request on a server side

Comment: Are the element ids (`RoleId`, `ProvinceId` and so on) correct? do you have these elements (with these exact ids) in the form you're posting?

Comment: Thanks, however this is not all. Can you also post a definition of a NewUser class? Also what exactly is happening - newUser is coming as null, or action method is not called at all?

Comment: I am receiving all other fields which is on the form at controller but receiving null on these fields.

Comment: I am getting the values on second time I submit the form but not on first time. why?

Comment: change ``OnBegin ="return setValues()"`` to ``OnBegin ="setValues"``

Comment: not working for me. When I debugged jquery.unobtructive the default value of element is set But I am not getting into the controller